# MKPinAnnotationView color is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I am trying to show some pins from an array, it shows them all but they are red, and not green as i ask them to be.

Why is that ?

```
 //run on array to get all locations
for(int k=0;k<[array count];k=k+2)
{

        float targetlat=[[array objectAtIndex:k] floatValue];
        float targetlongi=[[array objectAtIndex:k+1] floatValue];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location =  CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(targetlat,targetlongi);
        NSString *partyTitle = @"title";
        MKPinAnnotationView *partyPin = [self returnPointView:location andTitle:partyTitle andColor:MKPinAnnotationColorGreen];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:partyPin.annotation];

}

   //function callback is working but its red, and it takes so much time to load
-(MKPinAnnotationView*) returnPointView: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) location andTitle: (NSString*) title andColor: (int) color
{


    MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;
    region.center = location;
    region.span.longitudeDelta /= 5.0;
    region.span.latitudeDelta /= 5.0;
    [self.mapView setRegion:region];

    MKPointAnnotation *resultPin = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    MKPinAnnotationView *result = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:resultPin reuseIdentifier:Nil];
    [resultPin setCoordinate:location];
    resultPin.title = title;
    result.pinColor = color;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: also animation is not working with result.animatesDrop=yes; . seems that he don't even care about my properties

Comment: `(int) color` try this into `NSUInteger`

Comment: thanx tried also to directly assign the value with no results, also the drop animation is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regarding the main issue that the pins are red instead of green:**

The code creates an `MKPinAnnotationView` but this view is *never given to the map view*.
To make the map view use annotation views that you create, ***you must implement the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method and return them from there***.
Otherwise, the map view has no knowledge of annotation views that you create.
If you don't implement `viewForAnnotation`, the map view creates a default red pin view.

**Regarding the second issue that "it takes so much time to load":**

The most likely reason for this is that you are calling `setRegion` *each* time you add an annotation.
If you are adding, say, 500 annotations, the map view is setting the region 500 times.
Please note that ***it is not necessary to call `setRegion` simply to add an annotation*** (regardless of the currently-visible region).  The annotation's coordinate does *not* have to be "visible" to add an annotation there.

What you want to do inside the `for` loop is simply *construct* a region that includes all the annotations and then call `setRegion` (or `setVisibleRect`) *once* and *after* all the annotations are added (after the `for` loop).  Constructing an `MKMapRect` and calling `setVisibleMapRect` is easier than constructing an `MKCoordinateRegion` in order to call `setRegion`.

In iOS 7, this is even simpler: Just call `showAnnotations` (no manual construction necessary).

Example:

```
//Initialize the MKMapRect (region) we want to show to null...
MKMapRect showMapRect = MKMapRectNull;

for(int k=0;k<[array count];k=k+2)
{
    float targetlat=[[array objectAtIndex:k] floatValue];
    float targetlongi=[[array objectAtIndex:k+1] floatValue];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location =  CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(targetlat,targetlongi);
    NSString *partyTitle = @"title";

    //Here, don't create the annotation view.
    //Just create the annotation...
    MKPointAnnotation *resultPin = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    [resultPin setCoordinate:location];
    resultPin.title = partyTitle;
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:resultPin];

    //Add this annotation's coordinate
    //to the MKMapRect we want to show...
    MKMapPoint annMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(location);
    MKMapRect annMapRect = MKMapRectMake(annMapPoint.x, annMapPoint.y, 0, 0);
    showMapRect = MKMapRectUnion(showMapRect, annMapRect);
}

mapView.visibleMapRect = showMapRect;

//In iOS 7, instead of constructing MKMapRect manually,
//we could just call showAnnotations...
//[mapView showAnnotations:mapView.annotations animated:YES];


//Implement the viewForAnnotation delegate method...
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    //if annotation is the user location,
    //return nil so map view shows default view for it (blue dot)...
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString *reuseId = @"pin";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pav = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
    if (pav == nil)
    {
        pav = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
        pav.canShowCallout = YES;
        pav.animatesDrop = YES;
        pav.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    }
    else
    {
        pav.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return pav;
}
```

Comment: Of course, don't forget to set/connect the map view's `delegate` otherwise the delegate method will not get called.