# MKCoordinate region from CLLocationDeCoordinate2D

Tags: objective-c, mapkit

I have an array of the following objects:

```
@interface House : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D locationCoord2D;
@end
```

I am trying to create the smallest `MKCoordinateRegion`, that will contain all houses in it. How can I achieve it?

Since now I was trying to use `valueForKeyPath` and `Min` and `Max` predicate, but with no good results.

Comment: Is this so that you can show all the houses on the screen together?  If the houses are annotation objects, you can just call showAnnotations in iOS 7.  Otherwise, use MKMapRectUnion() to build an MKMapRect ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127157/mkpinannotationview-color-is-not-working) and then set visibleMapRect or MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect().

Comment: But later I need to do more complicated options like: scale MKCoordinateRegion, compare if one touches other, etc. so using showAnnotations won't be enough for me.

Comment: So the MKMapRectUnion should help you.  Then you can use other functions like MKMapRectIntersectsRect, etc.  For scaling, it would probably be better to work with MKMapPoints than CLLocationCoordinate2Ds (just during the calculations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this;

1) Extend your House class like this to get latitude and longitude via instance methods.

```
@implementation House

- (id)initWithLatitude:(CLLocationDegrees)latitude longitude:(CLLocationDegrees)longitude {

    if (self = [super init]) {

        _locationCoord2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
    }
    return self;
}

+ (instancetype)houseWithLatitude:(CLLocationDegrees)latitude longitude:(CLLocationDegrees)longitude {

    return [[self alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
}

- (CLLocationDegrees)latitude { return _locationCoord2D.latitude; }

- (CLLocationDegrees)longitude { return _locationCoord2D.longitude; }

@end
```

NB: `Instance methods for latitude and longitude` are important for KVC.

2) Obtain your `MKCoordinateRegion` like this

```
CLLocationDegrees maxLatitude = [[houses valueForKeyPath:@"@max.latitude"] doubleValue];

CLLocationDegrees minLatitude = [[houses valueForKeyPath:@"@min.latitude"] doubleValue];

CLLocationDegrees maxLongitude = [[houses valueForKeyPath:@"@max.longitude"] doubleValue];

CLLocationDegrees minLongitude = [[houses valueForKeyPath:@"@min.longitude"] doubleValue];

MKCoordinateRegion coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(minLatitude + (maxLatitude - minLatitude)/2, minLongitude + (maxLongitude - minLongitude)/2), MKCoordinateSpanMake(maxLatitude - minLatitude, maxLongitude - minLongitude));
```

Everything is straightforward here. Add more delta for the margins. Thats it.